# Remove brackets from url with array of ids (Request.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, request

I have an application with nodejs express who makes request but when I pass an array I am:

Example: `/foo?id=1&id=3&id=5`

How to remove '[]' ?

```
var requestQueryParams = {id: [1,3,5]}

var options = {
        url: 'www.test.com',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'},
        qs: requestQueryParams || {}
    };

request.get(options), function(){...}
```

result: `www.test.com?id[0]=1&id[1]=3&id[2]=5`

Request.js = https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

Qs.js = https://www.npmjs.org/package/qs

`Qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] });
 // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c&a[2]=d'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution is override (request.Request.prototype.qs)

```
var qs = require('qs'),
request = require('request'),
url = require('url');

var stringify;
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

var isArray = Array.isArray || function (arr) {
return toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]';
};

var objectKeys = Object.keys || function (obj) {
var ret = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ret.push(key);
    }
}
return ret;
};

var stringifyString = function (str, prefix) {
if (!prefix) throw new TypeError('stringify expects an object');
return prefix + '=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
};

var stringifyArray = function (arr, prefix) {
var ret = [];
if (!prefix) throw new TypeError('stringify expects an object');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ret.push(stringify(arr[i], prefix));
}
return ret.join('&');
};

function stringifyObject(obj, prefix) {
var ret = [];
var keys = objectKeys(obj);
var key;

for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; ++i) {

    key = keys[i];

    if ('' === key) {
        continue;
    }

    if (null === obj[key]) {
        ret.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=');

    } else {
        ret.push(stringify(obj[key], prefix ? prefix + '[' + encodeURIComponent(key) + ']' :     encodeURIComponent(key)));
    }
}

return ret.join('&');
}

stringify = function (obj, prefix) {
if (isArray(obj)) {
    return stringifyArray(obj, prefix);
} else if ('[object Object]' === toString.call(obj)) {
    return stringifyObject(obj, prefix);
} else if ('string' === typeof obj) {
    return stringifyString(obj, prefix);
} else {
    return prefix + '=' + encodeURIComponent(String(obj));
}
};
```

And override prototype.qs :

```
request.Request.prototype.qs = function (q, clobber) {
var base;

if (!clobber && this.uri.query) {
    base = qs.parse(this.uri.query)
}
else {
    base = {}
}

for (var i in q) {
    base[i] = q[i]
}

if (stringify(base) === '') {
    return this
}

this.uri = url.parse(this.uri.href.split('?')[0] + '?' + stringify(base));
this.url = this.uri;
this.path = this.uri.path;

return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since some time now there is a better solution. `request` uses `qs` per default to stringify the passed in qs object which also accepts options for formatting it. One of this options is `arrayFormat` which accepts the following values:

- `indices`: Default behavior. Produces a string including the index:  `id[0]=foo&id[1]=bar&id[2]=baz`. Useful if you want to ensure the correct order.
- `brackets`: Produces a string with only brackets appended: `id[]=foo&id[]=bar&id[]=baz`.
- `repeat`: Produces a string without any brackets: `id=foo&id=bar&id=baz`. Older services that don't support arrays may accept this but will then only use the last value.

A options object with this would look like the following:

```
const request = require('request');
const options = { 
  ...
  qs: {
    id: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ],
  },
  qsStringifyOptions: { arrayFormat: 'repeat' },
};
request(options);
```

See also https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback, where that option is also mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want instead? If you want `www.test.com?id0=1&id1=3&id2=5`, then you need to give it a params object like this:

```
var requestQueryParams = { id0: 1, id1: 3, id2: 5 }
```

If you already have an object that looks like `{ id: [1,2,3] }`, then you need to convert that object into one like the above. You can do that in a `for` loop easily enough:

```
var requestQueryParams = { id: [1,3,5] },
    newRequestQueryParams = {};

for(var i = 0; i < requestQueryParams.id.length; i++) {
  var paramName = "id" + i, // "id0", "id1", etc.
      id = requestQueryParams.id[i];

  newRequestQueryParams[paramName] = id;
}

console.log(newRequestQueryParams);
// => { id0: 1, id1: 3, id2: 5 }
```

**Update:** If you want a query string like `id=1&id=3&id=5` (although this would be very strange, as I mention in my comment below), you can also do it in a `for` loop, as above, or you could do something like this:

```
var requestQueryParams = { id: [1,3,5] },
    queryStringParts = [], // an array this time
    queryString;

for(var i = 0; i < requestQueryParams.id.length; i++) {
  var param = "id=" + parseInt( requestQueryParams.id[i] );
  queryStringParts.push(param);
}
// queryStringParts is now [ "id=1", "id=3", "id=5" ]

queryString = queryStringParts.join("&")
console.log(queryString);
// => "id=1&id=3&id=5"
```

I used `parseInt` inside the `for` loop because I'm assuming the IDs are coming from an untrusted source (e.g. a user) and, since you're building a string manually instead of using a library that will encode the data for you, you want to prevent a malicious user from injecting arbitrary strings into your request. You could also use `encodeURIComponent`, but it's overkill if IDs should always be numbers.

Comment: I want to have the index.

Comment: *Where* do you want to "have the index"? I see you edited your question, which has unfortunately made it less clear. Is `id=1&id=3&id=5` the query string you want to end up with? Since it's a very non-standard format (with duplicate parameters most endpoints will take only the last, i.e. `id=1` and `id=3` will be ignored in favor of `id=5`), so you'll probably have to just build the string manually. I'll update my answer to show how you might do that.

Comment: @JordanRunning: Passing multiple parameters with the same name is the *standard* way of passing a list of values. Both in the query string and in POST data. Every web framework ought to support getting all the values.

Comment: That’s interesting, Matti. Can you give me a link to the standard?